# awk count specified char occur , return 0 if not found

Tags: awk

I have a textfile:

```
and

b

,

.

apple

banana
```

and I want to count the occurrences of some specific characters which include semi_colon, in this case there's no semi_colon found

excepted output would be :
semi_colon 0

Here's my code:

```
sed -e 's/;/semi_colon/g' data.txt|awk '{count[$1]++} if(count[$1]==""){count[$1]=0} END{print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]}'
```

which gets the output like :

```
semi_colon
```

Wondering how to achieve the  expected output:

```
semi_colon 0
```

Cheers if anyone can help!

Comment: The *"Decorate and Process"* approach of substituting some value like `"semi_colon"`, is powerful when needed, but here there is no real need. You simply want to count the occurrences of whatever ASCII character you are looking for. Replacing a character with a string for that purpose doesn't really buy you anything.

Comment: Note that piping `sed` to `awk` might be often refactored into single `awk` as latter has rich set of tools for working with strings. In this particular case `sed` part might be replaced using `gsub` which is one of [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code.

```
awk '
{
  countA+=gsub(/a/,"&")
  countSemiColon+=gsub(/;/,"&")
}
END{
  print "a "countA+0 ORS "semi_colon " countSemiColon+0
}
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, in main block of `awk` program using `awk`'s `gsub` function/method to globally substitute `a` with itself(just for counting its occurrences sake) and putting its number of substitution occurrences into `countA` awk variable, where `+=` denotes that its value will keep adding to its previous value itself(to get TOTAL number of `a`'s in all lines).

Then creating variable named `countSemiColon` which has value of global substitutions of `;` in each line and it keep adding its all values from all lines to get all occurrences in whole Input_file. In `END` block of `awk` printing the value of variables `countA` and `countSemiColon` as per required output.

Comment: Nicely done Sir.

Comment: while the `gsub()` approach would work for chars that aren't regexp metachars, it'd need work to handle metachars. If you wanted to count 20 different chars then having 20 different scalar variables would be cumbersome.

Answer (score 2):

Using all awk to count characters in file:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {
    c[";"]="semi_colon"    # define chars to count and their nicknames
    c["a"]="a"
}
{
    split($0,t,"")         # split record between chars
    for(i in t)            # iterate every char in string
        f[t[i]]++          # count freqs
}
END {
    for(i in c)
        print c[i],f[i]+0  # +0 is the key to fix space to a zero
}' file
```

Output:

```
a 5
semi_colon 0
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin _I want to count the occurrences of some specific characters_ I really wasn't sure what the requirement means and the sample data of a missing desired character really didn't help either.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh lol, I seem to have cut the sample starting from the `b`. :D Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ,I think this is the point! (# +0 is the key to fix space to a zero)So sorry for the bad presentation though!

Comment: `split($0,t,//)` (using a null char as a field separator) is undefined behavior so what that does will vary across awk versions.

Comment: Lol, probably first time I ever tried that and completely forgot about it. I donät know if `""` is any better but at least it works with mawk, `//` didn't.

Comment: why not just use field splitting and iterate chars through the fields instead of an extra layer into an array ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for ( i=1; i<=length($0); i++ ) {
        cnt[substr($0,i,1)]++
    }
}
END {
    print "semi_colon", cnt[";"]+0
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
semi_colon 0
```

and for multiple chars:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    for ( i=1; i<=length($0); i++ ) {
        cnt[substr($0,i,1)]++
    }
}
END {
    chars = "a;."
    map[";"] = "semi_colon"
    for ( i=1; i<=length(chars); i++ ) {
        char = substr(chars,i,1)
        print (char in map ? map[char] : char), cnt[char]+0
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
a 5
semi_colon 0
. 1
```

Regarding your original code `sed -e 's/;/semi_colon/g' data.txt|awk...` - you never need sed when you're using awk and doing that would break your script if you also wanted it to count any of the letters that are present in the string `semi_colon` (e.g. `_`s or `e`s) or if the input contained a string that was `semi_colon` as you'd then have no way to differentiate that from an original `;`. In general, when desirable you should map symbols to strings in the output, not in the input.

Answer (score 1):

First, your `awk` script is not correct (typo?)

```
awk '
    {
        count[$1]++
    } 
    if(count[$1]=="")
    {
        count[$1]=0
    }
    END{
        print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]
    }
'
```

It should be

```
awk '
    {
        count[$1]++
        if(count[$1]=="")
        {
            count[$1]=0
        }
    }
    END{
        print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]
    }
'
```

That said, the

```
if(count[$1]=="")
{
    count[$1]=0
}
```

Is never called: since `$1` must have been matched when arriving here, `count[b1]` can't be "" (it's default value).

The idea is right, but you need to insert it in `END` block:

```
awk '
    {
        count[$1]++
    }
    END{
        if (count["semi_colon"] != "") {
            print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]
        } else 
        {
            print"semi_colon", 0
        }
    }
'
```

```
echo -e "and\nb\n,\napple\nbanana" | sed -e 's/;/semi_colon/g' |awk '  { count[$1]++  } END{ if (count["semi_colon"] != "") {  print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]  } else   {  print"semi_colon", 0  }  } '
```

But use [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72284855/1212012)

Comment: You don't need the `if..else` - just `print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]+0` or set `count["semi_colon"]=0` in the `BEGIN` section.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you have typo preventing your code from execution

```
awk '{count[$1]++} if(count[$1]==""){count[$1]=0} END{print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]}'
```

should be

```
awk '{count[$1]++}count[$1]==""{count[$1]=0} END{print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]}'
```

more importantly `count[$1]==""` never hold true, as it was done after `count[$1]++` meaning that during that check `count[$1]` is always integer equal or greater than 1. Therefore above code will always gives same output as

```
awk '{count[$1]++}END{print"semi_colon",count["semi_colon"]}'
```

As you are dealing with numeric values you might use `+0` as this used against empty string gives 0 and is neutral against known numeric values. If you wish more general way to provide placeholder for unknown value then combine `in` check with so called ternary operator, consider following example let `file.txt` content be

```
A
A
A
```

and you want to count `A`, `B`, `C` and output `not found` for these which did not exist, then you might use GNU `AWK` following way

```
awk '{cnt[$1]+=1}END{print "A:",("A" in cnt)?cnt["A"]:"not found","B:",("B" in cnt)?cnt["B"]:"not found","C:",("C" in cnt)?cnt["C"]:"not found"}' file.txt
```

output

```
A: 3 B: not found C: not found
```

Explanation: `in` is used for checking if array has key, so-called ternary operator has form of *condition*`?`*valueiftrue*`:`*valueiffalse*

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Answer (score 0):

```
{m/n/g}awk '
BEGIN {    ___ = " char::{ %3s } > freq::{ %5.f }\n"
           FS  = substr(_, OFS = _,   _ = ";")"a"
}  NF { __[_] +=   gsub(_,"&")+(__[FS] += --NF)*_
} END { 
       for(_ in __) { printf(___,_,__[_]) } }'
```

————————————————————————————————————————

```
 char::{   ; } > freq::{     0 }
 char::{   a } > freq::{     5 }
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72284624/awk-count-specified-char-occur-return-0-if-not-found/72284855?noredirect=1#comment127712485_72284931) and try with, for example,  `&`.

Comment: i never said mine was for any character - it's only for "a" and ";" per OP question. i have a full-fledge unicode character counter below that also could count arbitrary binary bytes, even in gawk-unicode mode, if that's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

if you want a full-fledged character freq counter, I just quickly slapped one together for `UTF-8`  :::

- it'll still work with other `awk` variants, just without the `unicode` bit
- even `gawk` in `unicode` mode can be used to count arbitrary bytes in ***binary files*** without triggering any error messages

  - *`I even threw an mp3 file at it`*

-- *unfortunately, a small bug remains - it's mis-classifying the `UTF-16 surrogate` range*

- in terms of performance, if you use `mawk 1.9.9.6/mawk2`, I just freq-counted a `408 MB` text file filled with `Unicode` in `21.7secs` :

————————————————

```
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \222 \x92 |     146 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[      128404 ] sumtotal >>[      405114168 ]
 char >>[    7 ]--[  U+     37 |      55 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[     4197205 ] sumtotal >>[      409311373 ]
 char >>[    H ]--[  U+     48 |      72 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[      212959 ] sumtotal >>[      409524332 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \355 \xED |     237 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[     4909733 ] sumtotal >>[      414434065 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \233 \x9B |     155 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[      747521 ] sumtotal >>[      415181586 ]
 char >>[    < ]--[  U+     3C |      60 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       42849 ] sumtotal >>[      415224435 ]
 char >>[    Q ]--[  U+     51 |      81 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[        8615 ] sumtotal >>[      415233050 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \352 \xEA |     234 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[     8878221 ] sumtotal >>[      424111271 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \240 \xA0 |     160 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[     4432353 ] sumtotal >>[      428543624 ]
( pvE 0.1 in0 < "${m3r}" | mawk2 ; )  21.59s user 0.25s system 100% cpu 21.734 total
```

```
    gawk/mawk 'BEGIN {
     1      _ = initEscRE(____) * split(FS = _, __, _)
     1      FS = "^$"
    }

    # Rule(s)

 50355  {
5049452     while (/./) {
5049452         ___ = sprintf("%.*s", ! _, $_)
5049452         __[___] += gsub(___ in ____ ? ____[___] : ___, "", $0)
        }
    }

    # END rule(s)

    END {
     1      initCHR(__, _____)
     1      PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_str_asc"
     1      ___ = ""
     1      OFMT = "%.f"
 18964      for (_ in __) {
 18964          print sprintf(" char >>[ %4s ]--[ %-35s ] freq >>[ %11.f ] sumtotal >>[ %14.f ]", _, _____[_], __[_], ___ += __[_])
        }
    }


    # Functions, listed alphabetically

     1  function initCHR(__, ___, _, ____, _____, ______)
    {
     1      split(_, ___, FS)
     1      ______ *= ______ = ____ = (_____ = _ = 4) ^ _
     1      _____ *= _____
1114112     for (_ = ______ - (-_ < +_) + ______ * _____; -_ <= +_; _--) {
1114112         ___[sprintf("%c", _)] = sprintf(" U+ %6X | %7.f (%s)", _, _, (_ + _) < (_____ * _____) ? "ASCII" : int((_ + _) / (____ * _____)) ~ "^5[45]$" ? "UTF16 surrogates" : "UTF8 " (4 - (_ < ______) - ((_ + _) < (____ * _____))) "-bytes")
        }
     1      ____ ^= ____ = (______ = _ *= _ += _ ^= _ < _) + _
     1      _ += _ = _ * _ * -_
     1      ______ ^= ______
   128      while (_ < -_) {
   128          ___[sprintf("%c", _ + ____)] = sprintf(" \\%o \\x%2X | %7.f (8-bit byte)", _ + ______, _ + ______, ______ + _++)
        }
    }

     1  function initEscRE(__, ___, _, ____)
    {
     1      split(_, __, FS) + split("!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~", ___, _)
    32      for (____ in ___) {
    32          _ = ___[____]
    32          __[_] = ("[") (index("^]\\/", _) ? "\\" : "") (_) ("]")
        }
     1      return (_ < _)
    }
```

———————————————————————————

```
 char >>[    s ]--[  U+     73 |     115 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       29805 ] sumtotal >>[        4706098 ]
 char >>[    t ]--[  U+     74 |     116 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       32722 ] sumtotal >>[        4738820 ]
 char >>[    u ]--[  U+     75 |     117 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       27833 ] sumtotal >>[        4766653 ]
 char >>[    v ]--[  U+     76 |     118 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       27453 ] sumtotal >>[        4794106 ]
 char >>[    w ]--[  U+     77 |     119 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       21278 ] sumtotal >>[        4815384 ]
 char >>[    x ]--[  U+     78 |     120 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       31107 ] sumtotal >>[        4846491 ]
 char >>[    y ]--[  U+     79 |     121 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       28413 ] sumtotal >>[        4874904 ]
 char >>[    z ]--[  U+     7A |     122 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       27555 ] sumtotal >>[        4902459 ]
 char >>[    { ]--[  U+     7B |     123 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       20195 ] sumtotal >>[        4922654 ]
 char >>[    | ]--[  U+     7C |     124 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       24009 ] sumtotal >>[        4946663 ]
 char >>[    } ]--[  U+     7D |     125 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       21986 ] sumtotal >>[        4968649 ]
 char >>[    ~ ]--[  U+     7E |     126 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       22780 ] sumtotal >>[        4991429 ]
 char >>[      ]--[  U+     7F |     127 (ASCII)        ] freq >>[       21827 ] sumtotal >>[        5013256 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \200 \x80 |     128 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       42532 ] sumtotal >>[        5110931 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \201 \x81 |     129 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       44412 ] sumtotal >>[        5155343 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \202 \x82 |     130 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       36002 ] sumtotal >>[        5191345 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \203 \x83 |     131 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       42798 ] sumtotal >>[        5234143 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \204 \x84 |     132 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       37037 ] sumtotal >>[        5271180 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \205 \x85 |     133 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       41117 ] sumtotal >>[        5312297 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \206 \x86 |     134 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       31655 ] sumtotal >>[        5343952 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \207 \x87 |     135 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       43455 ] sumtotal >>[        5387407 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \210 \x88 |     136 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       37021 ] sumtotal >>[        5424428 ]
 char >>[    ? ]--[  \211 \x89 |     137 (8-bit byte)   ] freq >>[       34333 ] sumtotal >>[        5458761 ]

 char >>[    ɣ ]--[  U+    263 |     611 (UTF8 2-bytes) ] freq >>[         112 ] sumtotal >>[        7412934 ]
 char >>[    ɤ ]--[  U+    264 |     612 (UTF8 2-bytes) ] freq >>[         118 ] sumtotal >>[        7413052 ]
 char >>[    ɥ ]--[  U+    265 |     613 (UTF8 2-bytes) ] freq >>[         104 ] sumtotal >>[        7413156 ]
 char >>[    ɦ ]--[  U+    266 |     614 (UTF8 2-bytes) ] freq >>[         101 ] sumtotal >>[        7413257 ]

 char >>[    ࠁ ]--[  U+    801 |    2049 (UTF8 3-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8089676 ]
 char >>[    ࠂ ]--[  U+    802 |    2050 (UTF8 3-bytes) ] freq >>[           3 ] sumtotal >>[        8089679 ]
 char >>[    ࠈ ]--[  U+    808 |    2056 (UTF8 3-bytes) ] freq >>[           2 ] sumtotal >>[        8089681 ]
 char >>[    ࠉ ]--[  U+    809 |    2057 (UTF8 3-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8089682 ]
 char >>[    ࠌ ]--[  U+    80C |    2060 (UTF8 3-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8089683 ]

 char >>[     ]--[  U+  27569 |  161129 (UTF8 4-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8539054 ]
 char >>[     ]--[  U+  28041 |  163905 (UTF8 4-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8539055 ]
 char >>[     ]--[  U+  282A8 |  164520 (UTF8 4-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8539056 ]
 char >>[     ]--[  U+  286F1 |  165617 (UTF8 4-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8539057 ]
 char >>[     ]--[  U+  2882A |  165930 (UTF8 4-bytes) ] freq >>[           1 ] sumtotal >>[        8539058 ]
```